# Can I open an aura component by giving it its api name/name as input?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, aura

I am looking for a way to open some aura components according to the user input

I could of course list all components and show the selected one but I was looking for a smarter and more dynamic way to do it, which would be to use the api name to invoke the correct aura.

Is there any way to accomplish it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can. See [Is Url Addressable](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:isUrlAddressable/documentation) for more details. In summary, though, you need to add `lightning:isUrlAddressable` to the component, and from there, you can navigate to the component using `lightning:navigation`:

```html
<lightning:navigation aura:id="navService"/>
```

```js
var navService = component.find("navService");
var pageReference = {
    type: 'standard__component',
    attributes: {
        componentName: 'c__helloTarget',
    },
    state: {
        "c__id": "001XXXXXXXXXXXX"
    }
};
navService.navigate(pageReference);
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Exactly what I needed! I'll look up the documentation for further details